# how do i add additional line items to a NetSuite order via API

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

our Shopify store syncs with NetSuite and we send orders with line items from Shopify to NS. However there are often situations where we need to enrich the orders in NS with zero value items that we don't want on the shopify order. E.g. marketing materials that we want to send out to the customer.

- SuiteQL isn't an option as there is no way to add / update
- SOAP API seems like a winner but good-god it's complicated
- Could i build a complex rules engine in suite script that looks at the order and based on whatever it add line items?

any advice from someone who has done it before would be great?

Answer (score 0):

You can use User-Event/Workflow or Map-Reduce/Scheduled/Mass-Update scripts which will filter orders, and update orders.

Comment: thanks for answering, ill look into it. Do you know anyway to do it via the API?